# Write a C++ code to count the number of a’s in a string

Tags: c++

I've written the code below, but it's giving a number of errors:

```
15  13  C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Error] no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and 'char')
15  28  C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Error] no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and 'char')
16  3   C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp    [Error] expected ')' before 'count'
```

And some more.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int len,i,count=0;
    string str[len];
    cout<<"Enter the length for your string:";
    cin>>len;
    cout<<"Enter the characters for your string:";
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    cin>>str[i];
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(str[i]=='a'||str[i]=='A')
        count++;
    }
    cout<<"Number of 'a' and 'A' in your string is "<<count<<".";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is this supposed to be a single string of length `len` : `string str[len];` ? Even if it worked that way you read `len` from the user after you declared `str`

Comment: Simpler: `string str; cin >> str;` and then check the size of `str` etc. In this case, `str[i]` will be a character, not a `string`.

Comment: In your own words, where you have written `string str[len]`, what do you expect that to mean? In particular, what do you expect the value of `len` to be at this point, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making this WAY too hard.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count=0;
    string str;

    cout<<"Enter the characters for your string:";
    getline(cin, str);

    for (char c: str) {
        if (c == 'a' || c == 'A')
            count++;
    }
    cout<<"Number of 'a' and 'A' in your string is "<<count<<"." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My changes from yours:

1. I got rid of len and the index. You don't need them.
2. I used getline() to get an entire line. The loop is just silly.
3. I used a simpler form of a for-loop to loop through the characters.
4. And I added an endl to the final cout.

Answer (score 2):

One major reason to favour `std::string` over plain character arrays is that `std::string` can resize easily. You need not tell a `std::string` its size beforehand.

This:

```
string str[len];
```

Is an array of strings. Its size is `len`, but `len` is uninitialized, hence your code has undefined behavior.

A single string is this:

```
std::string str;
```

You don't need to, but if you still want you can resize a string upfront. Though if you do that you still should **not** keep track of its size seperately from the string. It has a `size()` method and to loop all characters in the string you can use a range-based loop:

```
std::string str;
std::cout << "Enter the length for your string:";
std::cin >> len;
str.resize(len);
std::cout << "Enter the characters for your string:";
for(auto& c : str) std::cin >> c;
```

`str[i]` is then the i-th character in the string. In your code `str[i]` is the i-th string in the array. Thats why you get an error about mixing characters (`'A'`) and strings (`str[i]`).

Comment: 12 16 C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp [Error] range-based 'for' loops are not allowed in C++98 mode

Comment: @Mazhar what compiler are you using? C++98 lacks most features that you need to write up to date C++. If your compiler is not too old, it should at least support C++11 via `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x`

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring an *array* of strings (and doing so *incorrectly* at that).  Then you are filling the array with `len` number of strings not characters, and then trying to compare each string to a single character.  But `std::string` does not have an `operator==` for that comparison, which is exactly what the first 2 errors are telling you.

Get rid of the array, you should be working with a single `std::string` instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int len, i, count = 0;
    char ch;
    std::string str;

    std::cout << "Enter the length for your string:";
    std::cin >> len;

    std::cout << "Enter the characters for your string:";
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        std::cin >> ch; // or: std::cin.get(ch)
        str.push_back(ch);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (str[i] == 'a' || str[i] == 'A')
            ++count;
    }

    std::cout << "Number of 'a' and 'A' in your string is " << count << ".";
    return 0;
}
```

You can take that a step further by also getting rid of `len` too, let `std::cin` populate the string for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    std::string str;

    std::cout << "Enter your string:";
    std::cin >> str; // or: std::getline(std::cin, str);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (str[i] == 'a' || str[i] == 'A')
            ++count;
    }

    std::cout << "Number of 'a' and 'A' in your string is " << count << ".";
    return 0;
}
```

And then you can get rid of the `for` loop too, by using the standard [`std::count_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) algorithm, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string str;

    std::cout << "Enter your string:";
    std::cin >> str; // or: std::getline(std::cin, str);

    size_t count = std::count_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
        [](char ch){ return (ch == 'a' || ch == 'A'); }
    );

    std::cout << "Number of 'a' and 'A' in your string is " << count << ".";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This declares an array of `std::string`'s, not a single string with the length `len`:

```
string str[len];
```

Instead declare a `std::string` and use `std::getline` to read whatever it is that the user types in. You can then use `std::ranges::count_if` (or `std::count_if` prior to C++20) to count the number of `a`:s and `A`:s in the string:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::ranges::count_if, std::count_if
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main() {
    std::string str;
    std::cout << "Enter the characters for your string:";
    std::getline(std::cin, str);

    // a lambda to check if an individual character is an 'a' or 'A'     
    auto a_or_A_lambda = [](char ch) { return ch == 'a' || ch == 'A'; };

    // use count_if and with the lambda
    auto count = std::ranges::count_if(str, a_or_A_lambda);
    
    // prior to C++20:
    //auto count = std::count_if(str.begin(), str.end(), a_or_A_lambda);

    std::cout << "Number of 'a' and 'A' in your string is "<< count << ".\n";
}
```